# Struggling to add drop down effect to navbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've been struggling to get my navbar on mobile to transition downwards when the hamburger menu is pressed. I have added CSS and looked into things but I'm struggling to understand why it isn't working.

I'd like the navbar to drop down and the opacity of the links to change.

I have used an answer below to adapt my code but I am still encountering difficulties.

Thanks in advance.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if(x.className.indexOf('easein') > -1) {
    x.classList.remove('easein');
    x.classList.add('easeout')
  }
  else {
    x.classList.add('easein');
    x.classList.remove('easeout')
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
        display: block;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 16px 2px red;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 45;
        right: 0;
        width: 100vw;
      }

      .topnav a#home {
          left: 0;
      }
      
      .topnav .myLinks {
        height: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      }
      
      .topnav a {
        color: #0000a0;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 700;
        display: block;
      }
      
      .topnav a.icon {
        background: #fff;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 4vw;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
      }
      .fa {
          color: red;
      }

      #myLinks a{
        left: -10%;
        border-radius: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .topnav .myLinks.easein {
        height:500px;
        opacity: 1;
      }
      
      .topnav .myLinks.easeout {
        height:0px;
        opacity: 0;
      }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="topnav">
        <a href="#home" class="online">Logo</a>
        <div id="myLinks" class="myLinks">
            <a href="#news">Portal</a>
            <a href="#contact">Feedback</a>
            <a href="#about">Logout</a>
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: just replace `.topnav #myLinks` with `.topnav .myLinks`, using ID selector will cause the CSS rule to always applied and override anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have set the CSS attribute display to have the animation, I suggest that you change it to `opacity` and `height`, also note that I used [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add/remove class, here is an implementation of what you are looking for:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if(x.className.indexOf('easein') > -1) {
    x.classList.remove('easein');
    x.classList.add('easeout')
  }
  else {
    x.classList.add('easein');
    x.classList.remove('easeout')
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 16px 2px red;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.topnav a#home {
    left: 0;
}

.topnav .myLinks {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.topnav a {
  color: #0000a0;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.fa {
    color: red;
}

.myLinks a{
  width: 100vw;
}

.topnav .myLinks.easein {
  height:500px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.topnav .myLinks.easeout {
  height:0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="topnav">
    <a href="#home" class="online">Logo</a>
    <div id="myLinks" class="myLinks">
        <a href="#news">Portal</a>
        <a href="#contact">Feedback</a>
        <a href="#about">Logout</a>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've adapted my code but I am still encountering an issue. Might you be able to take a look good sir?  Thanks for your time

Comment: @AliShahVis, if you find my answer helpful please accept and upvote it :)

Comment: I will good sir, just trying to get it to work on my side. Having some issues to get it to work

Comment: @AliShahVis, I hope its working for you now, I added a comment stating the issue in your question snippet, let me know if its not working yet! will help for sure.